# Blinking UILabel Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

Is it possible to make a blinking UILabel in Cocoa Touch or do I need an UIview with Core Animation for that?

Comment: **Warning!** Blinking user interface elements can trigger epileptic seizures if they blink at certain frequencies. Be careful when implementing such animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fun, I decided to write this subclassing NSOperation.

Excerpt from BlinkingLabelOperation.m

```
- (void)main {
    SEL update = @selector(updateLabel);
    [self setThreadPriority:0.0];

    while (![self isCancelled]) {
        if (label_ == nil)
            break;

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:interval_];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:update withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}

- (void)updateLabel {
    BlinkingColors *currentColors = nil;

    if (mode_)
        currentColors = blinkColors_;
    else
        currentColors = normalColors_;

    [label_ setTextColor:currentColors.textColor];
    [label_ setBackgroundColor:currentColors.backgroundColor];

    mode_ = !mode_;
}
```

Sample view controller code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    BlinkingColors *blinkColors = [[BlinkingColors alloc] initWithBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]
                                                                        textColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    BlinkingLabelOperation *blinkingOp = [[BlinkingLabelOperation alloc] initWithLabel:clickLabel freq:1.0 blinkColors:blinkColors];

    // put the operation on a background thread
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
    [queue addOperation:blinkingOp];

    [blinkColors release];
}
```

For a complete listing, you will find it [here](https://gist.github.com/954637). Please leave comments and let me know what are your thoughts.

Comment: Hi Black Frog, thanks a lot for your answer and your code! Very nice and ease to implement, works great and is exactly what I was looking for.Two thumbs up :-)

Answer (score 2):

Take Martin's advice, and then have a look at [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) to handle the "blink" actions.

[+ scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval%3atarget%3aselector%3auserInfo%3arepeats%3a)

Comment: If you want to get fancy, you can animate it on and off with the alpha value.

Comment: It's just for  3 seconds, to show a paused audio player state. Nothing harmful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All UIViews (including UILabel) has a `hidden` property which you can toggle on and off to make it "blink".

Comment: Martin, thanks for pointing that out. At this point just an UILabel suits my needs.